# Query planner thinks doing a sequential scan on a very large table is faster than using an index?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I've got a query that selects the most favorited photo for each of the last 12 editions for a particular domain (this is just a segment of a larger query, but the problem seems to stem from here):

```
WITH
    selected_editions AS (
        SELECT
            editions.*
        FROM
            editions JOIN
            domains USING (community_id)
        WHERE
            domains.name = 'www.example.com'
            AND editions.name <= now()
        ORDER BY
            editions.name DESC
            LIMIT 12
        )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (edition_id)
    photos.*,
    edition_id,
    community_id,
    event_id
FROM
    selected_editions
    JOIN edition_event_maybes ON edition_event_maybes.edition_id = selected_editions.id
    JOIN event_photos USING (event_id)
    JOIN photos ON photos.id = event_photos.photo_id
ORDER BY
    edition_id,
    photos.favorites DESC
```

Right now, all photos have 0 favorites (I don't have the trigger in place yet to update this column), but the query is just as slow if I drop the sort on that column.  For some reason, the query planner has determined that doing a sequential scan on photos (which has over 1.5M records) is faster than using the indexes I have in place:

```
 Unique  (cost=372256.50..372935.22 rows=7365 width=334) (actual time=154536.566..154608.510 rows=10 loops=1)
   CTE selected_editions
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..54.22 rows=12 width=36) (actual time=4.925..53.899 rows=12 loops=1)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..284.65 rows=63 width=36) (actual time=4.902..53.600 rows=12 loops=1)
                 Join Filter: (public.editions.community_id = domains.community_id)
                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 746
                 ->  Index Scan using editions_name_desc_idx on editions  (cost=0.00..212.99 rows=4226 width=36) (actual time=0.081..9.468 rows=758 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (name <= now())
                 ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.023 rows=1 loops=758)
                       ->  Index Scan using domains_pkey on domains  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.108..0.144 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'www.example.com'::text)
   ->  Sort  (cost=372202.28..372541.64 rows=135744 width=334) (actual time=154536.538..154572.782 rows=2894 loops=1)
         Sort Key: public.editions.id, photos.favorites
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 936kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=93971.72..318867.75 rows=135744 width=334) (actual time=128046.409..154460.268 rows=2894 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (photos.id = event_photos.photo_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on photos  (cost=0.00..83395.70 rows=1555170 width=322) (actual time=29.002..38235.655 rows=1555170 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=91611.92..91611.92 rows=135744 width=16) (actual time=73723.507..73723.507 rows=2894 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 4096  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 19kB
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=91.76..91611.92 rows=135744 width=16) (actual time=50381.167..73683.577 rows=2894 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=91.76..62163.87 rows=6408 width=16) (actual time=47309.596..73452.213 rows=1300 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (event_communities.community_id = public.editions.community_id)
                                 Join Filter: ((public.editions.date_start <= (max(public.event_dates.date_end))) AND (public.editions.date_end >= (max(public.event_dates.date_end))))
                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 65504
                                 ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..60081.31 rows=300177 width=20) (actual time=0.166..65913.681 rows=471703 loops=1)
                                       Merge Cond: (public.event_dates.event_id = event_communities.event_id)
                                       ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..37516.38 rows=285686 width=12) (actual time=0.107..30174.408 rows=466853 loops=1)
                                             ->  Index Scan using event_dates_event_id_idx on event_dates  (cost=0.00..31789.93 rows=573917 width=12) (actual time=0.055..11274.795 rows=573918 loops=1)
                                       ->  Index Scan using event_communities_event_id_idx on event_communities  (cost=0.00..14812.83 rows=471702 width=8) (actual time=0.023..9308.039 rows=471703 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=91.61..91.61 rows=12 width=28) (actual time=55.305..55.305 rows=12 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..91.61 rows=12 width=28) (actual time=5.010..55.140 rows=12 loops=1)
                                             ->  CTE Scan on selected_editions  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=12 width=8) (actual time=4.949..54.232 rows=12 loops=1)
                                             ->  Index Scan using editions_id_key on editions  (cost=0.00..7.60 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.016..0.028 rows=1 loops=12)
                                                   Index Cond: (id = selected_editions.id)
                           ->  Index Only Scan using event_photos_pkey on event_photos  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=21 width=8) (actual time=0.020..0.096 rows=2 loops=1300)
                                 Index Cond: (event_id = public.event_dates.event_id)
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 154610.261 ms
(39 rows)
```

Here's the same query with sequential scans disabled:

```
 Unique  (cost=1074619.92..1075298.64 rows=7365 width=334) (actual time=94494.393..94577.865 rows=10 loops=1)
   CTE selected_editions
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..54.22 rows=12 width=36) (actual time=3.573..79.361 rows=12 loops=1)
           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..284.65 rows=63 width=36) (actual time=3.548..79.050 rows=12 loops=1)
                 Join Filter: (public.editions.community_id = domains.community_id)
                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 746
                 ->  Index Scan using editions_name_desc_idx on editions  (cost=0.00..212.99 rows=4226 width=36) (actual time=0.093..10.826 rows=758 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (name <= now())
                 ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.012..0.025 rows=1 loops=758)
                       ->  Index Scan using domains_pkey on domains  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'www.example.com'::text)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1074565.70..1074905.06 rows=135744 width=334) (actual time=94494.369..94537.576 rows=2894 loops=1)
         Sort Key: public.editions.id, photos.favorites
         Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 944kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=91.76..1021231.16 rows=135744 width=334) (actual time=63179.391..94438.900 rows=2894 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=91.76..91611.92 rows=135744 width=16) (actual time=63179.301..93417.564 rows=2894 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=91.76..62163.87 rows=6408 width=16) (actual time=59254.420..91777.586 rows=1300 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (event_communities.community_id = public.editions.community_id)
                           Join Filter: ((public.editions.date_start <= (max(public.event_dates.date_end))) AND (public.editions.date_end >= (max(public.event_dates.date_end))))
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 65504
                           ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.00..60081.31 rows=300177 width=20) (actual time=0.132..80756.825 rows=471703 loops=1)
                                 Merge Cond: (public.event_dates.event_id = event_communities.event_id)
                                 ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..37516.38 rows=285686 width=12) (actual time=0.077..44386.794 rows=466853 loops=1)
                                       ->  Index Scan using event_dates_event_id_idx on event_dates  (cost=0.00..31789.93 rows=573917 width=12) (actual time=0.027..22761.032 rows=573918 loops=1)
                                 ->  Index Scan using event_communities_event_id_idx on event_communities  (cost=0.00..14812.83 rows=471702 width=8) (actual time=0.020..9425.884 rows=471703 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=91.61..91.61 rows=12 width=28) (actual time=112.148..112.148 rows=12 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..91.61 rows=12 width=28) (actual time=34.863..111.959 rows=12 loops=1)
                                       ->  CTE Scan on selected_editions  (cost=0.00..0.24 rows=12 width=8) (actual time=3.600..79.708 rows=12 loops=1)
                                       ->  Index Scan using editions_id_key on editions  (cost=0.00..7.60 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=2.619..2.633 rows=1 loops=12)
                                             Index Cond: (id = selected_editions.id)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using event_photos_pkey on event_photos  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=21 width=8) (actual time=1.088..1.126 rows=2 loops=1300)
                           Index Cond: (event_id = public.event_dates.event_id)
                           Heap Fetches: 0
               ->  Index Scan using photos_pkey on photos  (cost=0.00..6.84 rows=1 width=322) (actual time=0.188..0.202 rows=1 loops=2894)
                     Index Cond: (id = event_photos.photo_id)
 Total runtime: 94579.633 ms
(37 rows)
```

Here are the indexes for photos/event_photos:

```
create index event_photos_event_id_idx on event_photos(event_id);
create index event_photos_photo_id_idx on event_photos(photo_id);

create index photos_active_idx on photos(active);
create index photos_user_id_idx on photos(user_id);
create index photos_date_added_idx on photos(date_added);
create index photos_favorites_idx on photos(favorites);
create index photos_favorites_desc_idx on photos(favorites DESC);
```

edition_event_maybes is actually a view, but I don't think it is related to the problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW edition_event_maybes AS
SELECT
    event_dates.event_id,
    editions.id AS edition_id
FROM
    (SELECT event_id, max(date_end) AS date_end FROM event_dates GROUP BY event_id) AS event_dates JOIN
    event_communities USING (event_id) JOIN
    editions USING (community_id)
WHERE
    editions.date_start <= event_dates.date_end AND
    editions.date_end >= event_dates.date_end;
```

Is there something I've missed that would cause this bottleneck?  Changing the query to use a subquery instead of a CTE still causes a sequential scan on the photos table.

```
 Unique  (cost=388072.43..388758.52 rows=7365 width=334) (actual time=95404.014..95469.743 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=388072.43..388415.47 rows=137218 width=334) (actual time=95403.965..95437.141 rows=2894 loops=1)
         Sort Key: public.editions.id, photos.favorites
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1597kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=109237.10..334146.54 rows=137218 width=334) (actual time=49556.700..95365.375 rows=2894 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (photos.id = event_photos.photo_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on photos  (cost=0.00..83394.73 rows=1555073 width=322) (actual time=0.048..20448.423 rows=1555170 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=106850.77..106850.77 rows=137227 width=16) (actual time=49467.987..49467.987 rows=2894 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 8192  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 35kB
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=19732.99..106850.77 rows=137227 width=16) (actual time=36904.902..49432.907 rows=2894 loops=1)
                           ->  Merge Join  (cost=19732.99..75716.63 rows=6424 width=20) (actual time=35270.958..49286.796 rows=1300 loops=1)
                                 Merge Cond: (public.event_dates.event_id = events.id)
                                 ->  Merge Join  (cost=19732.99..62334.85 rows=6424 width=16) (actual time=28501.498..38919.456 rows=1300 loops=1)
                                       Merge Cond: (public.event_dates.event_id = event_communities.event_id)
                                       Join Filter: ((public.editions.date_start <= (max(public.event_dates.date_end))) AND (public.editions.date_end >= (max(public.event_dates.date_end))))
                                       Rows Removed by Join Filter: 65504
                                       ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..37500.55 rows=284288 width=12) (actual time=0.269..18824.228 rows=466846 loops=1)
                                             ->  Index Scan using event_dates_event_id_idx on event_dates  (cost=0.00..31788.08 rows=573918 width=12) (actual time=0.084..7061.177 rows=573912 loops=1)
                                       ->  Materialize  (cost=19732.99..20186.60 rows=90721 width=28) (actual time=12017.842..14224.345 rows=66804 loops=1)
                                             ->  Sort  (cost=19732.99..19959.80 rows=90721 width=28) (actual time=12017.464..12774.118 rows=66804 loops=1)
                                                   Sort Key: event_communities.event_id
                                                   Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 2480kB
                                                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=145.88..10089.01 rows=90721 width=28) (actual time=2211.610..11195.388 rows=66804 loops=1)
                                                         Hash Cond: (event_communities.community_id = public.editions.community_id)
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on event_communities  (cost=0.00..7267.03 rows=471703 width=8) (actual time=0.165..5138.541 rows=471703 loops=1)
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=145.73..145.73 rows=12 width=28) (actual time=62.562..62.562 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                                               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..145.73 rows=12 width=28) (actual time=5.694..62.355 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                                     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..54.24 rows=12 width=36) (actual time=5.603..61.340 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..284.74 rows=63 width=36) (actual time=5.552..61.014 rows=12 loops=1)
                                                                                 Join Filter: (public.editions.community_id = domains.community_id)
                                                                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 746
                                                                                 ->  Index Scan using editions_name_desc_idx on editions  (cost=0.00..213.04 rows=4229 width=36) (actual time=0.157..10.830 rows=758 loops=1)
                                                                                       Index Cond: (name <= now())
                                                                                 ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.027 rows=1 loops=758)
                                                                                       ->  Index Scan using domains_pkey on domains  (cost=0.00..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.058..0.096 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                                             Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'www.snapbram.com'::text)
                                                                     ->  Index Scan using editions_id_key on editions  (cost=0.00..7.60 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.016..0.029 rows=1 loops=12)
                                                                           Index Cond: (id = public.editions.id)
                                 ->  Index Only Scan using events_pkey on events  (cost=0.00..12134.45 rows=466810 width=4) (actual time=0.036..5276.910 rows=466846 loops=1)
                                       Heap Fetches: 0
                           ->  Index Only Scan using event_photos_pkey on event_photos  (cost=0.00..4.64 rows=21 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.041 rows=2 loops=1300)
                                 Index Cond: (event_id = public.event_dates.event_id)
                                 Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 95475.120 ms
(45 rows)
```

Version info: PostgreSQL 9.2 on a virtual machine running OpenBSD 5.3 amd64.  PostgreSQL settings are the defaults.

Comment: Can I get some more info on your configuration? What's your work_mem set at? What's shared_buffers? And what version of PG are you using and on which architecture? The query plan seems to indicate that your sorts are being stored on disk (944kB) so maybe your work_mem needs to increase so sorts can happen in memory.

Comment: Your query planner's theoretical row counts are way off from the actual row counts. This is one of my red flags for bad statistics. For instance, your top level sort is expecting 135744 rows and the actual number of rows is 2894.

Comment: I've increased work_mem from 1MB to 2MB, shared_buffers is 128MB.  The sort is now in memory, but it hasn't changed the cost.

Comment: For some reason the row count estimates are way off. If the query planner is trying to determine the selectivity trade-off of your index, it's probably determining that a sequence scan would be more cost effective. Your nested loops are estimating 135744 rows but only getting back 2894. Can you vacuum analyze full to rebuild all the tables or is it a production database? Can you rebuild the indexes? Tom Lane suggests raising statistics targets. Can you try disabling nested joins just to see how the costs vary (enable_nestloop )?

Comment: Also, if you can spare it, I would raise shared buffers to one gigabyte and see if that makes any difference. If your entire database is cached in memory buffers, then there will be no reason for the planner to take disk costs into account? (and since you're on FreeBSD, be careful because raising shared_memory too high without changing some OS memory settings might cause PG to crash).

Comment: One thing is pretty clear,namely that the disk of the VM is extremely slow. 40k ms for 400k index rows is just terrible...  Otherwise you can replace the CTE with a subquery, so that the information you get only 12 rows is not hidden behind the optimization fence.  I don't see the statistics being off, the estimates of every sequential or index scan are quite good.

Comment: @dezso The sequential scan is a concern for me since that table is expected to grow very rapidly (~70,000 per month initially).

Comment: @cimmanon Could you post the plan for the change I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your query, I think the planner is making the right choice, you have no WHERE clause or LIMIT, so the database has to return every row anyway, so it has the choice look at the entire table and look at the indexes or look at the entire table.

Have you tried restricting the rows with a WHERE clause or used a limit?  I cant think of many time critical uses cases where you would want to look at 1.5 million rows.

Answer (score -2):

The query planner is somewhat mysterious and it can be hard to understand its decisions. My guess is bad statistics or a configuration that doesn't reflect your actual hardware situation. Since your query runs about 60 seconds faster with sequence scans disabled, it would appear that the query planner is making a bad decision.

You can rebuild your statistics with VACUUM or ANALYZE. I doubt it's a bad index, but you can also try rebuilding your indexes with REINDEX.

The query planner might also be using the default settings in your configuration file, which might not be optimized for your machine. For instance, if you're running your database on an SSD, the default read/write/random settings in the config file might be giving PostgreSQL an inaccurate impression of your machine's hardware).

Here are a couple of articles I've found interesting regarding PG configuration as well as some docs:

[The performance of Postgresql: SSD vs consumer HDD](http://it-blog.5amsolutions.com/2010/08/performance-of-postgresql-ssd-vs.html)

[18.6. Query Planning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-query.html)

[Random Page Cost Revisited](http://www.databasesoup.com/2012/05/random-page-cost-revisited.html)

[ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-analyze.html)

[REINDEX](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reindex.html)

[FORCING THE PLANNER'S HAND WITH SET ENABLE_SEQSCAN OFF WTF](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/149-Forcing-the-planners-hand-with-set-enable_seqscan-off-WTF.html)

It looks like you've already used the following options, but I'll put them here explicitly for anyone who finds this post and wonders how you turned off sequential scans.

```
set enable_seqscan=false;
set enable_indexscan=true;
```

Comment: The query planner is not a a mysterious entity.  With the docs and the output from explain it is possible to understand the decisions it's made. For instance, here, having to read the entire table is cheaper than having to read the entire table and the indices from disk.

Comment: There's no "superiority" here. You simply made wrong statements and someone called you out on it. They were harsh, and I don't think that was unjustified given your statement. Furthermore, your final advice to explicitly disable sequential scans is actually quite bad, as there are definitely times when it is desirable.